# Sort a list of lists according to another list

Tags: python, list, sorting

How would you sort `lista` according to order of items in `sorter_list`:

```
lista = [["John", "B3"],["Robert", "P3"], ["Thomas", "S2"]]

sorter_list = ["P3", "S2", "B3"]
```

and result will be:

```
sorted_lista = [ ["Robert", "P3"], ["Thomas", "S2"], ["John", "B3"]]
```

Regards

Comment: Your `sorter_list` has `S2` instead of `S4`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although  @F.J has a perfect solution, my question is, why aren't you using a dictionary for storing this kind of data in the first place?

***With dictionary:***

```
d = {'B3': 'John', 'P3': 'Robert', 'S2': 'Thomas'}
sorter = ["P3", "S2", "B3"]
print([(d[key], key) for key in sorter])
```

***Output:***

```
[('Robert', 'P3'), ('Thomas', 'S2'), ('John', 'B3')]
```

**Plus:** You should also check the `collections` module's `OrderedDict`.

**UPDATE:**

Of course, you can store the values as lists, so one can hold multiple values:

***With dictionary:***

```
d = {'B3': [('John', 123)], 'P3': [('Robert', 465), ('Andres', 468)], 'S2': [('Thomas', 19)]}
sorter = ('P3', 'B3', 'S2')
print([(d[key], key) for key in sorter])
```

***Output:***

```
[([('Robert', 465), ('Andres', 468)], 'P3'), ([('John', 123)], 'B3'), ([('Thomas', 19)], 'S2')]
```

*In this case, you can also use a dictionary inside a dictionary:*

```
d = {'B3': {'John': 123}, 'P3': {'Robert': 465, 'Andres': 468}, 'S2': {'Thomas': 19}}
```

*And the lookup will be much easier later on.*

Comment: Thanks, I wondered how to sort if sorter is a list instead of a dictionary.

Comment: There is one thing you need to know: if `sorter` has a key, that `d` doesn't have this code snippet will raise a `KeyError`!

Comment: I noticed something, more than 1 people can have "P3" as sorting item, such as  `[["John", "B3"],["Robert", "P3"], ["Andres", "P3"], ["Thomas", "S2"]]`

Comment: Yepp, that is one thing a dictionary can't have: two keys that are the same.. so if you want to prevent this, use the name for they keys, and the Letter+Digit combo.. I will update my code!

Comment: And lista's items can have multiple elements, that's why data is stored in a list, such as `[["John", "B3", 123],["Robert", "P3", 465], ["Andres", "P3",468], ["Thomas", "S2",19]]`

Comment: I updated my answer, check it!

Comment: Thank you for taking your time :)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming there will always be an entry in `sorter_list` that matches the second element of each list in `lista`:

```
sorted_lista = sorted(lista, key=lambda lst: sorter_list.index(lst[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in O(N) by building a dictionary, where your keys are the `B3`, `S2` etc.

```
lookup_dict = dict( (item[1],item) for item in lista)
sorted_lista = [ lookup_dict[key] for key in sorter_list ]
```

This takes advantage of the fact that your `sorter_list` is already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

To sort efficient I think it's better to create a dictionary from `sorter_list`

```
sorter_dict = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(sorter_list)}
sorted_lista = sorted(lista, key=lambda lst: sorter_dict[lst[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm newbie in python so it may not be the most optimized solution

```
sorted_lista=[]

for i in sorter_list:
    for j in lista:
        if i==j[1]:
            sorted_lista.append([j[0],j[1]])

print sorted_lista
```

Output :

```
[['Robert', 'P3'], ['Thomas', 'S2'], ['John', 'B3']]
```